# postgresql update where like other table

Tags: postgresql, match

I have a table with 18000 rows. Each for a different city or village. This table contains coordinates for every location.

Some of these entries are badly written containing error. But I have another table containing all the cities spelled accurately.

Is there anyway to update the table containing the coordinates matching the names of the table with the correct names?

i.e.

```
table with coordinates      | table with correct name
Pariss                      | Paris
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the misspellings are extra characters at the beginning or end of the names in the coordinates table (as in your example), then the query should be something simple like this:

```
UPDATE table_with_coordinates AS x
  SET ... (do your stuff)
  FROM table_with_correct_name as y
  WHERE y.name LIKE '%' || x.name || '%';
```

You may also test your mettle with regular expressions, but that means a lot of work, specially if you're not familiar with them.

If, however, the misspellings are can include something like 'P4ris', then the requirement is  more complex and it escalates into the realm of fuzzy string comparison. The idea is to test for strings that a certain amount of patterns and grade them. Then you'll choose a significant grade to consider you're string as a misspell. If you want to use Postgres capabilities, here's [a good primer](http://viget.com/extend/alternatives-to-sphinx-fuzzy-string-matching-in-postgresql) (be sure to check the links at the bottom too) that may be useful.

Comment: Fuzzy matching will be the way to go, but be careful. You'll probably need to check the matches, because some of your city names will be similar enough to each other that they might trigger the fuzzy matching themselves. Or a typo could make a city name more similar to a _different_ city's name. For setting the threshold, start with the greatest similarity between any pair of correctly spelled cities.